Is 51 Poise still the Magic Number for PVE?
It’s widely accepted that 51 Poise is the ‘magic number’ for PVE content in Elden Ring. (See this Wiki article). This is because all NPC attacks in the base game deal 10, 50, or 100 points of poise damage. Thus, 51 is sufficient poise to absorb two 50 point hits before staggering, while 101 poise has been considered to be not reasonably attainable.
Do these breakpoints remain the same in Shadow of the Erdtree? Certainly the available poise levels haven’t significantly increased (sets went up to 99.99 without talismans in the base game and go up to 101 in the DLC). So it seems reasonable that a target of 51 would remain the sweet spot, but if it’s increased, I’d like to plan for that in my build.
